# Announcing an upcoming election

Tags: discussion

**Summary**: Sound Design Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://sound.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **July 19**, as your "graduation" election (as a result of [having lost your beta label](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1418/13263) a while back).

The timeline:

- On July 12, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on July 19, users can [nominate themselves](https://sound.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- On July 26, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not four or more candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 3 (or on the 10th, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 4 or more candidates then).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** After having an insufficient number of candidates at the closing of the extension of the nomination period, the election has been cancelled. The CM team will follow up with the moderation team to figure out next steps and update the community once we do.

---

The nominations for the election have been extended for another week (until August 2, 2021) as we need more candidates. Please consider helping the moderation team and and this community's first election, by nominating in [the election page](https://sound.stackexchange.com/election/1)!